# How to find most similar string values in a dataframe?

Tags: pandas, search, nlp

I am finding the similarity between the sentence using embedding sentence and looping through all the document's embedded sentences to find the right match relative to the search string. I also want to display the document name in the output along with the similarity match result but am not sure how I can extract that information from the dataframe respective to the sentence we get in the output result. I have tried the index method but it is not showing me the correct document name.

Please guide how can I get the document name in the result output along with the sentence.

My data frame looks like this:

```
Document name        Document sentences in tokens

Doc 1                 [Sentence 1, sentence 2, sentence 3]

Doc 2                 [Sentence 1, sentence 2, sentence 3]
```

I have used the following code to find the top 10 matches with the search string.

```
from itertools import chain
docs_sent_tokens=list(chain.from_iterable(main_df['Sentence_Tokenize_rules']))
docs_name=main_df['Document name']


results=[]

#set the threshold value to get the similarity result accordingly
threshold=0

#embedding all the documents and find the similarity between search text and all the tokenize sentences
for docs_sent_token in docs_sent_tokens:

#To find the document name
    for index in main_df.index:
        doc_name= main_df['Document name'][index]

    sentence_embeddings = model.encode(docs_sent_token)
    sim_score1 = cosine_sim(search_sentence_embeddings, sentence_embeddings)
    if sim_score1 > threshold:
            results.append((
                docs_sent_token,
                sim_score1,
                doc_name

                ))

#printing the top 10 matching result in dataframe format
df=pd.DataFrame(results, columns=['Matching Sentence','Similarity Score','Docuemnt name'])

# sorting in descending order based on the similarity score
df.sort_values("Similarity Score", ascending = False, inplace = True)

#change the value of n to see more results
df.head(n=10)
```

Output should be like this:

```
Matching sentence    similarity score    document name
Sentence 12              0.80            doc 1
sentence 15              0.69            doc 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can do it using Python standard library [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html) module, which provides helpers for computing deltas.

Given the following toy dataframe and search sentence:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "document": ["doc 1", "doc 2"],
        "sentences": [
            ["lore ipsum", "magna carta", "upside down"],
            ["tempus fugit", "memento mori", "lora ipsom"],
        ],
    }
)
search_sentence = "lor ipsum"
```

Define a helper function to compare sentences similarity:

```py
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def ratio(a, b):
    return round(SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio(), 2)
```

And then:

```py
# Use Python instead of Pandas
df = df.to_dict(orient="list")

# Init empty dictionary
results = {"Matching sentence": [], "similarity score": [], "document name": []}

# Iterate to compare
for (doc, sentences) in zip(df["document"], df["sentences"]):
    for i, sentence in enumerate(sentences):
        results["Matching sentence"].append(f"Sentence {i+1}")
        results["similarity score"].append(ratio(search_sentence, sentence))
        results["document name"].append(doc)
```

Finally:

```py
new_df = (
    pd.DataFrame(results)
    .sort_values(by="similarity score", ascending=False)
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)

print(new_df)
# Ouptut
  Matching sentence  similarity score document name
0        Sentence 1              0.95         doc 1
1        Sentence 3              0.84         doc 2
2        Sentence 2              0.29         doc 2
3        Sentence 3              0.20         doc 1
4        Sentence 1              0.19         doc 2
5        Sentence 2              0.10         doc 1
```